# pycharm not recognizing str(), int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, vagrant, pycharm

Whenever I do `str(integer)` to cast to string, pycharm would highlight the str part and claim Unresolved Reference 'str'

Why? I thought str is a built in python function that should work universally.

I have Python 3.5 running from Vagrant configured as the interpreter that is setup following this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-vagrant.html

I tried invalidating cache from Pycharm but it didn't work

Comment: Does the code still work when you run it?

Comment: yea it works when i run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your project interpreter is right.

   `import sys
    print(sys.version)`
2. Back up and then remove `~/.PyCharm40` folder,it will remove your preferences and then restart Pycharm.
3. Delete your project's `.idea` folder and restart Pycharm.
4. `File` -> `Invalidate Caches/Restart` .

---

If the code works well when you run it,I suppose the second or third plan can fix this issue.

Hope this helps.